# Angular $resource called after api is initialized, resulting in empty return values

Tags: javascript, rest, user-interface, angularjs

I am trying to build a basic rpg like simple web game. I have a java server that provides a rest api to a pure html5 application.

This application has a service that returns quests by category. It also allows the user to view details about the quest. The quests are given through a rest api. I am reading this api using the $resource dependency.

The problem is, I have a service that is defined like this:

```
(function( ng, app ) {

    "use strict";

    // I provide a repository for the quests.
    app.service(
    "questService",
    function( $q, $resource, $http, _, categoryService ) {

        var QuestbookAPI = $resource( 'http://174.126.249.6\\:8080/worldcraft/quests' , {}, { query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true} });

        var quests = [];

        QuestbookAPI.query(function(newQuests){
            console.log("I ran !!!!! WOOTZORS . I am the questbook api query.");
            quests = newQuests;
            _.each(quests, function(quest){
                quest.id = quest.questID.id;
                quest.categoryID = quest.questCategory.id;                  
            });
        });

        // ***** general questbook api
        function getQuestByID( id ){}
        function getQuestsByCategory( categoryId ){}
        ....
        // ***** end general questbook api
        // I get the quest with the given ID.

        // Return the public API.
        return({
            getQuestByID: getQuestByID,
            getQuestsByCategoryID: getQuestsByCategoryID,
            getRandomQuestExcluding: getRandomQuestExcluding,
        });


    }
    );

})( angular, Worldcraft );
```

for some reason, when the controller using this service calls for getQuestsByCategoryID, the resource query does not run.

If I leave the page and revisit it, the query runs and the quests array is populated how I expected it.

My question is, why isn't my query running before anything else? I feel like I am missing a very fundamental concept.

the git for the project is on github at

https://github.com/ClinkWorks/Worldcraft-UI

the running project is at

http://www.clinkworks.com/worldcraft-ui

If you click quests, and then combat, go back a level, and hit combat again you can see what I mean.

For some reason the getQuestsByCategoryID function is running way before QuestbookAPI.query() even though the query is ran right when the service is declared... I am pretty confused..

I know its something to do with promises... or the $q object, but i'm not quite sure how.

Comment: $resource.query calls are all asynchronously filled. There's no guarantee the call will execute before all your other code runs. Your caller should be the one running the callback inside query & setting it to a $scope variable. You can then use a $watch to check for the assignment & do something after the data has arrived.

Comment: @Fool could you please answer this question with your comment? I did this work a while ago, but its what I needed. Your reply was a great answer.

Comment: Done! Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$resource.query` calls are all asynchronously filled. There's no guarantee the call will execute before all your other code runs.

Your caller should be the one running the callback inside `query` & setting it to a `$scope` variable. You can then use a `$watch` to check for the assignment & do something after the data has arrived.